uWSGI Workers Hanging with 100% CPU Usage After Respawn
I’m facing a peculiar issue with uwsgi==2.0.28-1 on newly deployed servers. Specifically, my workers are hanging when they’re supposed to respawn, causing them to max out the CPU at 100%.
After attaching GDB to one of the stuck workers, I traced the hang to the following:
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f8642c3a069 in SpinLock::lock (this=0x55a9104d9724) at src/spinlock.h:27
#1  std::lock_guard<SpinLock>::lock_guard (__m=..., this=<synthetic pointer>) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/std_mutex.h:159
#2  HeapProfiler::HandleFree (ptr=0x7f863571fd30, this=0x55a9104d9720) at src/heap.h:116
#3  (anonymous namespace)::WrappedFree (ctx=0x7f8642d120b0 <(anonymous namespace)::g_base_allocators+80>, ptr=0x7f863571fd30) at src/malloc_patch.cc:95
#4  0x00007f864bd2781b in PyUnicode_FromFormatV () from target:/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#5  0x00007f864bd2ba90 in PyErr_Format () from target:/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#6  0x00007f864bd208db in _PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict () from target:/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#7  0x00007f864bd350e2 in PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject () from target:/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#8  0x00007f864bddfa99 in PyImport_ImportModuleLevel () from target:/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#9  0x00007f864bd580fe in PyImport_Import () from target:/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#10 0x00007f864bddfa3d in PyImport_ImportModule () from target:/usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#11 0x00007f864bfc0ada in get_uwsgi_pydict () from target:/usr/lib/uwsgi/python_plugin.so
#12 0x00007f864bfbd460 in uwsgi_python_atexit () from target:/usr/lib/uwsgi/python_plugin.so
#13 0x000055a90e2c3811 in uwsgi_plugins_atexit ()
#14 0x00007f864e3d8697 in __run_exit_handlers () from target:/usr/lib/libc.so.6
#15 0x00007f864e3d883e in exit () from target:/usr/lib/libc.so.6
#16 0x000055a90e276650 in uwsgi_exit ()
#17 0x000055a90e2c3867 in end_me ()
#18 0x000055a90e2c73aa in uwsgi_ignition ()
#19 0x000055a90e2cbdca in uwsgi_worker_run ()
#20 0x000055a90e2cc360 in uwsgi_run ()

For context, here’s my uwsgi configuration:
[uwsgi]
master = true
single-interpreter = true
disable-logging = false
log-4xx = true
log-5xx = true
master-fifo = /var/tmp/service.fifo
heartbeat = 10
uid = tech
guid = tech
thunder-lock = true
enable-threads = true
vacuum = true
workers = 160
plugin = python
socket = /opt/service/service.sock 
stats = 127.0.0.1:4402
chmod-socket = 666
chdir = /opt/service
venv = /opt/service/venv 
module = application.wsgi:application
logto = /var/log/service/service_uwsgi.log 
pidfile2 = /var/tmp/service.pid
procname = Service worker
procname-master = Service master 
need-app = true
hook-pre-app = exec:sudo chown tech:tech /var/log/service/*.log 
listen = 2048
harakiri = 120
buffer-size = 16384
max-request = 1000
max-worker-lifetime = 1200
max-worker-lifetime-delta = 60
reload-on-rss=1024

Interestingly, this problem does not occur on another server with a similar configuration.
To get things working, I had to use the skip-atexit option, which results in the worker process terminating forcefully. I’m unsure if this is the best approach.
Has anyone faced a similar issue? How did you address it? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
